# How can I mux a MKV and MKA file and get it to play in a browser?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm using ffmpeg to merge .mkv and .mka files into .mp4 files. My current command looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i audio.mka output_path.mp4
```

The audio and video files are pre-signed urls from Amazon S3. Even on a server with sufficient resources, this process is going very slowly. I've researched situations where you can tell ffmpeg to skip re-encoding each frame, but I think that in my situation it actually does need to re-encode each frame.

I've downloaded 2 sample files to my macbook pro and have installed ffmpeg locally via homebrew. When I run the command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i audio.mka -c copy output.mp4
```

I get the following output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '319_audio_1498590673766.mka':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2017-06-27T19:10:58.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:03.53, start: 2.831000, bitrate: 50 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Audio
Input #1, matroska,webm, from '319_video_1498590673766.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2017-06-27T19:10:58.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:03.97, start: 2.851000, bitrate: 224 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
[mp4 @ 0x7fa4f0806800] Could not find tag for codec vp8 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

So it appears that the specific encodings I'm working with are vp8 videos and opus audio files, which I believe are incompatible with the .mp4 output container. I would appreciate answers that cover ways of optimally merging vp8 and opus into .mp4 output or answers that point me in the direction of output media formats that are both compatible with vp8 & opus and are playable on web and mobile devices so that I can bypass the re-encoding step altogether.

EDIT:

Just wanted to provide a benchmark after following LordNeckbeard's advice:

```
4 min 41 second video transcoded locally on my mac

LordNeckbeard’s approach : 15 mins 55 seconds (955 seconds)
Current approach : 18 mins 49 seconds (1129 seconds)

18% speed increase
```

Comment: If the input formats are compatible with the MP4 output container add `-c copy` to just mux and avoid re-encoding. It will be much faster.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard So the resulting command would be ffmpeg -i video.mkv -c copy -i audio.mka -c copy output_path.mp4? Also, .mp4 is MPEG-4 and .mkv and .mka are Matroska, so I'd imagine they are incompatible. Am I wrong there?

Comment: I've attempted to follow the docs and copy using ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i audio.mka -c copy output.mp4 but it's writing 0 byte files, so clearly something is wrong.

Comment: is there a reason why you are not using the Matroska merge tool mkvmerge ?

Comment: @ScottStensland I'm not familiar with mkvmerge. Does it offer advantages over ffmpeg?

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -i video.mkv -c copy -i audio.mka -c copy output_path.mp4`. That command says: take the streams (video/audio/subtitles/*) from within each input and place them all together in a new mp4 container. The `-c copy` option is per-input-file.

Comment: @Robert Correct command is what you tried: `ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i audio.mka -c copy output.mp4`; possibly not compatible video and/or audio formats, but it is not possible to debug without more information. Show the complete console output from this command. You can [edit] your question to add this info instead of trying to cram it into comments.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Good point. I ran that sample command locally and updated my question with the output. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Robert VP8 video and Opus audio don't go into MP4. You'll need to re-encode. You can use a faster [x264 encoding preset](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#a2.Chooseapreset) to increase encoding speed.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thank you for the response. In your opinion, is it worth it to specify custom encoding parameters vs letting ffmpeg sort it out? I would imagine they would be libx264 and audio in aac.

Comment: @Robert I should clarify that Opus in MP4 is considered experimental, but it does you no good. No need to mess with custom encoding parameters: `-crf` and `-preset` are all you need (and `-profile:v` for more limited devices).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `ffmpeg` to mux and/or re-encode MKV and MKA into web browser compatible formats such as Webm or MP4.

## Webm mux: If the input formats are VP8/VP9 video with Vorbis or Opus audio

You can just mux into Webm if your inputs are VP8 or VP9 video and Vorbis or Opus audio, such as the inputs in your question. This should be fast because it will not re-encode:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i audio.mka -c copy output.webm
```

Default [stream selection](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior is to select one stream per stream type, so with `-map` you can tell it which streams to choose to prevent mistakes. For example, if both inputs contain multiple streams, but you only want to first video stream from `video.mkv` and the first audio stream from `audio.mka`:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i audio.mka -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c copy -movflags +faststart output.webm
```

## MP4 mux: If the input formats are H.264/H.265 video and AAC audio

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i audio.mka -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- `-movflags +faststart` was added because you mentioned web playback. This will allow the video to begin playback before it is completely downloaded by the client.

## Webm Re-encode: If the input formats are not compatible with Webm

You'll need to re-encode:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i audio.mka -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 33 -b:v 0 -c:a libopus output.webm
```

- VP9 is really slow. If you want VP8 instead use `-c:v libvpx`. For more info see [FFmpeg Wiki: VP8](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8) and [FFmpeg Wiki: VP9](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9).
- If you don't have libopus support use libvorbis instead.

## MP4 Re-encode: If the input formats are not compatible with MP4

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i audio.mka -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- For video, control quality with `-crf` and encoding speed with `-preset`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) and [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) for more info.
- If your target devices are limited in the H.264 profiles they support you can add `-profile:v main` or `-profile:v baseline`.

## `ffprobe` for scripting

You can make a script to automate this. `ffprobe` can be used to determine the formats:

```
$ ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of csv=p=0 video.mkv
h264
$ ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of csv=p=0 audio.mka 
aac
```

The `ffprobe` outputs can be used as variables in an if/then statement.

Comment: that is a fantastic answer. I'm going to try out your re-encoding solution very shortly. Do you happen to be aware of any output formats compatible with vp8 and opus that are also playable on web & mobile? Ideally, I would like to use the copy approach as the efficiency gains seem drastic.

Comment: @Robert I wasn't aware that you wanted web playback, or why you needed MP4 in the first place. I'll update the answer slightly. You can put VP8/VP9 video and Opus in webm. Should be playable by Firefox and Chrome at least.

Comment: I should have been more specific, I apologize. That's sounds like a great solution. Looking forward to it!!

Comment: @Robert Updated. I'm not a VP*/Webm user so refer to the links for more info on encoding using those formats.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the help. I would upvote you 1000 times if I could! Converting to webm locally took < 1 second... wow!